# how to use setLocation to move componets

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to set the components of this application to a set location using setLocation so far i haven't been able to move the components. There is more code but its get calling and setting this code for the most part. any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;



public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5793357804828609325L;

    public HangmanPanel(){

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Welcome to the Hangman App");
        JButton Button = new JButton("Ok");
        //Button.addActionListener();   
        JLabel tfLable = new JLabel("Please Enter a Letter");
        JTextField text = new JTextField(10);

        String input = text.getText();
        heading.setLocation(50, 20);
        tfLable.setLocation(20, 100);
        text.setLocation(320, 50);
        Button.setLocation(230, 100);

        this.add(heading);
        this.add(tfLable);
        this.add(text);
        this.add(Button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have a layout that does not allow you to move the components freely

Comment: Don't use `setLocation/setSize/setBounds`, that's the job of a LayoutManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `setLocation()` to layout Swing components, it is much better to use a Layout. Please have a look at [these Layout Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: If i add this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); to my code it just makes the JButton cover the window...

Comment: @Sage1216 Well just adding a line of code and calling it a day will rarely help you :) If you want to understand how Swing lays out components, you will need to read some of the tutorials found on the left-sided menu in the link I provided.

Comment: @Sage1216 used appropriately, `BorderLayout` is very useful. Just don't put your button in the center. Check out the various LayoutManager available to produce different layouts

Comment: I'm trying to use the BorderLayout at the moment... but it says to use  Button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50)); to size it... not working btw... I apologize I'm new to the GUI interface... I have my hole project done in a .java file with out the GUI... and half done on android but this JPanel is very complicated